# How to overflow image inside a toolbar using Ionic?

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework, sass

I am trying to overflow the image inside the toolbar like these:

```css
ion-header {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary);
  ion-toolbar {
    --padding-end: 30px;
    --padding-start: 30px;
    --min-height: 100px;
    ion-avatar {
      margin: 20px auto;
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      img {
        margin-top: 60%;
        border: 3px solid var(--ion-color-secondary);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-buttons slot="secondary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" size="large" name="exit"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-buttons slot="primary">
      <ion-button>
        <ion-icon slot="icon-only" size="large" name="create"></ion-icon>
      </ion-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-avatar>
      <img src="https://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8314104-1x1-940x940.jpg">
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

But I get a result like these, with the avatar cropped:

[image]

How can I achieve the same result but without cropping the image?

This is the result I want to get:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar color="primary">
    <ion-button slot="start">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" size="large" name="exit"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-button slot="end">
      <ion-icon slot="icon-only" size="large" name="create"></ion-icon>
    </ion-button>
    <ion-avatar>
      <img src="https://www.abc.net.au/news/image/8314104-1x1-940x940.jpg" />
    </ion-avatar>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-header {
  background: var(--ion-color-primary);
  ion-avatar {
    margin: 20px auto;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
  }
}
```

You will get this output:

[image]

I recommend you to go through the Ionic components as well: https://ionicframework.com/docs/components

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. If you see the result picture attached you'll see the image is cropped on the bottom, I want to avoid that.

Comment: @JordiGallego Please check my answer again. I have made some changes. I hope that will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the time, but I am not explaining very well what I'm looking for. I have modified my question to show the expected result.

Comment: @JordiGallego No worries, now I can see what you want to do. I have done a similar page like that too but the way I have done it is a bit different. What I did was I did not put the avatar inside the header toolbar, instead, I placed it inside the content and used ion-grid rows and cols to place the picture in the middle of the line. So, I have created a grid at the top which looked like a toolbar and used it like that.

Comment: Thanks, it helped a lot! I used your solution and finally I got the image right.

Comment: @JordiGallego no worries my friend. Please set my answer as solution if it helped you :)